# Nextjs 12-14 middleware caching

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I want to check in an interval for payment status of a logged in user. Not being paid, the middleware should "redirect to a not paid page".

However, after doing a lot of research all the caching options provided by nextjs are not valid for the middleware due to the nature of the edge runtime, including the fetch caching.

Is there any other option to enable some kind of caching in the middleware?